Is "as" used as pronoun in "Such....as" in sentences?
Here in below a sentence from 'Word power made easy Norman lewis' book.

The church proscribes, or announces a proscription (pro-SKRIP-shon) against, such activities as may harm its parishioners.

In above sentence, could "as" be replaced with "that".If so, then it seem to me that "as" working as pronoun(But as far as I know, "as" is not used as pronoun).
Is grammatically correct the use of 'as' in above sentence? If no, then what is the right structure? If yes, then why it is correct?
Please explain!!!

The construction such NP as VP means roughly “whatever NP may VP” or, equivalently, “any NP that VP.” And now that you have this explanation, you should be able to understand any such similarly formed sentences as may be encountered. If not, then feel free to enquire further about such sentences as cause you confusion.
And yes, you could call as here a relative pronoun.
And the construction such that introduces a clause. So no, it is not interchangeable with such … as.

Can we write "such activities which may harm it parishioners" in place of "as"?

No, that would not be at all idiomatic. (Never mind the fact that it would have to be “its parishioners.”)

But  'as' working as 'which'(as you have said 'as' working as relative pronoun)on the above right?

“whatever NP may VP” there is already "may " present in question sentence. So, would it be "whatever activities may harm...." or "whatever activities may may harm....(double 'may')"?

I. Explanation of "such...as" in the sentence
The sentence and query:

The church proscribes, or announces a proscription (pro-SKRIP-shon) against, such activities as may harm its parishioners..
In above sentence, could "as" be replaced with "that".If so, then it seem to me that "as" working as pronoun(But as far as I know, "as" is not used as pronoun).

Explanation:.
Here is the explanation of the
"such _ _ as"  construction (Reference Collins dictionary)

Function of "as":.
In this sentence, "as" is not a pronoun; it functions as a  conjunction introducing a descriptive clause ("may harm its parishioners") that specifies the type of activities.
"Such...as" Construction:.
According to the Collins Dictionary, "such...as" links a noun (modified by "such") to a clause introduced by  "as", which describes or specifies the kind of thing or person being referred to.
Role of "such":.
In the sentence, "such" is a determiner that modifies the noun  "activities", specifying which activities are being referred to (those that may harm parishioners).
Comparison to "such...that" sentence:.
While  "such...as" specifies or categorizes, "such...that" expresses cause and result.
Example:
He was such a good teacher that we all passed the exam..
Here, "such" functions as an intensifier, and "such...that" works as a correlative conjunction linking cause and result.

II. Supporting Reference:.
"Such...as" from Collins Dictionary:

such - determiner meaning.
You use such...as to link something or someone with a clause in which you give a description of the kind of thing or person that you mean.

Each member of the alliance agrees to take such action as it deems necessary.
Britain is not enjoying such prosperity as it was in the mid-1980s



So, can I understand like, "such activities as (it) may harm its parishioners." where "it" is hidden or understandable here?

@Ansh Yes. "it" or  "they". You can interpret it as:

...such activities as (they) may harm its parishioners.
Here, "they" or "it" would refer to "activities" because the clause introduced by "as" is specifying the kind of activities being referred to.

